# Total vorticity generation in 3D

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

In 2D flows, the total vorticity generation for an impulsively started plate can be found by measuring the circulation of the flow. This gives the vorticity generated per unit length.

I would like to do the same thing except for a 3D object that is impulsively set into motion. For example, a sphere that impulsively starts spinning at 1 revolution per second. Circulation is a measure to total vorticity in 2D on a surface but what is the measure of total vorticity in a 3D volume when vorticity is a vector and has multiple components?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in two dimensions, vorticity is given by $\omega=\partial_x v_y -\partial_y v_x$.  The analogous definition in three dimensions is $\omega=\nabla\times v$, where $\nabla\times$ is the curl operator (these derivative operators can be expressed as differential forms if you prefer).

Now a fundamental result of vector calculus is [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), which relates the flux of the curl of a vector field through a surface $S$ to the line integral around the boundary of $S$.  In two dimensions, the only surfaces available are on the plane (and the only flux available is perpendicular to the surface). Applying Stokes' theorem in two dimensions tells us the circulation $\Gamma_\gamma$ about a curve $\gamma$, defined by $\Gamma_\gamma=\oint_\gamma v(x(s))\cdot \frac{dx}{ds}ds$, is also given by $\int_{S_\gamma}\omega(x)d^2x$ where $S_\gamma$ is the (oriented) surface that forms the interior of $\gamma$.

We can also apply Stokes' theorem in 3D to determine circulation from vorticity: letting $\ell(s)$ be a differentiable closed curve in three dimensions, we have
$$
\Gamma_\gamma \equiv \oint_\gamma v(\ell)\cdot d\ell = \int_{S_\gamma}\omega(x)\cdot\hat n(x)dA,
$$
where $S_\gamma$ *is any nice surface in three dimensions whose boundary is $\gamma$*. With this in mind, to determine the components of vorticity at a point you should

1. Pick three small surfaces that intersect the point, with mutually orthogonal normal vectors.
2. For each surface, measure the circulation about the boundary and divide by the area.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same definition (effectively).

Circulation is the flux of vorticity through a control surface:

$$ \Gamma = \iint_S \vec{\omega} \cdot d\vec{S} $$

So in 3D, you define your control surface (which will now be a shell) and you compute the integral of the vorticity dotted with the surface normal at each location.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the above approach is that there are infinite 3D surfaces bounded by $\gamma$ and it is theoretically impossible to come with a unique value. Unfortunately, circulation in 3D cannot currently described with the present formulations.